# Getting issue after setup the PWA in magento2 venia theme

Tags: reactjs, magento2, progressive-web-apps, magento2.4, venia

After the installation, I have got an error

```
{{#pageTypeNonce}}{{#webpackChunks}}{{/webpackChunks}} {{/pageTypeNonce}}
```

Also, the child category product is displayed but the main category product is not displaying kindly check the below image

[image]

Also when we go to the product detail page again we are getting Oops!

Looks like the page you were hoping to find doesn't exist. Sorry about that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to run the site through upward server

You need to run

```
yarn start
```

When you run yarn watch it is generating upward server. You can change the upward production server details and port from .env file

```
STAGING_SERVER_PORT=8080
```

```
STAGING_SERVER_HOST=yourhost.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Try install module - Swissup 2 UPWARD connector module

https://github.com/swissup/module-upward-connector